# custom 404 not work in Nginx + Passenger fr Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

My Rails server environment is `Nginx` with `Passenger` and works fine so far.

Now I want to customize the `404` page, so I changed the `nginx` configuration like this:

```
...

error_page  404       /404.html;

...
```

Unfortunately it's not working. Does Passenger affect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that `nginx` handles the error pages, then you need to set the option [`passenger_intercept_errors`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#passenger_intercept_errors) to `on`. After that change you can use the normal `error_page` option of `nginx`.

Maybe you also want to set [`passenger_friendly_error_pages`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerFriendlyErrorPages) to `off`, so you could create your own start up messages.

As @Dominik mentioned, you need to put your custom error pages (`404.html`) into the `public/` folder of your app root.

Answer (score 1):

in rails you simply put your 404.html in the public folder of your app (where the document root is too)

Comment: This should be the answer from the Rails end, but from the server side, handling the errors could also be an issue